# Adding GPS location EXIF tag to video recordings with AVAssetWriter

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I'm trying to record a video from the Camera using `AVAssetWriter`.

The video recording works perfectly fine, but I cannot figure out how to add GPS location EXIF tags to the video files (mp4/mov).

I tried this:

```swift
func initMetadataWriter() throws {
  let locationSpec = [
    kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_Identifier: AVMetadataIdentifier.quickTimeMetadataLocationISO6709,
    kCMMetadataFormatDescriptionMetadataSpecificationKey_DataType: kCMMetadataDataType_QuickTimeMetadataLocation_ISO6709,
  ] as [String: Any]
  let metadataSpecifications: NSArray = [locationSpec]
  var metadataFormatDescription: CMFormatDescription?
  CMMetadataFormatDescriptionCreateWithMetadataSpecifications(allocator: kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                              metadataType: kCMMetadataFormatType_Boxed,
                                                              metadataSpecifications: metadataSpecifications,
                                                              formatDescriptionOut: &metadataFormatDescription)

  let metadataInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .metadata, outputSettings: nil, sourceFormatHint: metadataFormatDescription)
  guard assetWriter.canAdd(metadataInput) else {
    throw CameraError.location(.cannotWriteLocationToVideo)
  }
  assetWriter.add(metadataInput)
  metadataWriter = AVAssetWriterInputMetadataAdaptor(assetWriterInput: metadataInput)
}

private func createLocationMetadataItem(location: CLLocation) -> AVMetadataItem {
  let metadataItem = AVMutableMetadataItem()
  metadataItem.key = AVMetadataKey.commonKeyLocation as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
  metadataItem.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpace.common
  metadataItem.value = String(format: "%+.6f%+.6f/", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude) as (NSCopying & NSObjectProtocol)?
  metadataItem.identifier = AVMetadataIdentifier.quickTimeMetadataLocationISO6709
  return metadataItem
}

/**
 Writes a Location tag to the video
 */
func writeLocationTag(location: CLLocation) throws {
  guard let metadataWriter else {
    throw CameraError.location(.cannotWriteLocationToVideo)
  }

  let metadataItem = createLocationMetadataItem(location: location)
  let metadataGroup = AVTimedMetadataGroup(items: [metadataItem],
                                           timeRange: CMTimeRange(start: CMTime.zero, end: CMTime.positiveInfinity))
  metadataWriter.append(metadataGroup)
}
```

Then this will be called like this:

```swift
// 1. Initialize all AVAssetWriters and adapters
let recordingSession = RecordingSession(...)
try recordingSession.initVideoWriter()
try recordingSession.initAudioWriter()
try recordingSession.initMetadataWriter() 

// 2. Start writing
recordingSession.start()

// 3. While video/audio frames are being written, also write the GPS Location metadata:
let location = locationManager.location!
try recordingSession.writeLocationTag(location: location)
```

But this crashes with the following error:

```
-[AVAssetWriterInputMetadataAdaptor appendTimedMetadataGroup:] Cannot write to file timed metadata group 0x283ebd150: No entry in format description 0x281f3ff70 for metadata item 0x283cece80 with identifier mdta/com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709, data type com.apple.metadata.datatype.UTF-8 and extended language tag (null).  If you created this format description using -[AVTimedMetadataGroup copyFormatDescription], make sure the instance of AVTimedMetadataGroup used to create the format description contains a representative sample of metadata items which includes an item with the same combination of identifier, dataType, and extended language tag as this one
```

Has anyone successfully written GPS location tags to video files with `AVAssetWriter` before?

My AVAssetWriters support both `.mov` and `.mp4` (h264 and h265/hevc) videos.

Thanks!